# binding data to controller on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My application loads a list of objects into a tab, and the user is supposed to click on one of the lines of the tab to choose wich object he wants, and then I will do a request to the server using data specific to the object on the line he clicked.

Here is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez8tF.jpg

So this tab is generated through a ng-repeat, like so:

```
                <tr ng-repeat="event in eventListCrtl.eventList.eventHead">
                    <td> <button ng-click="submitEventChoice()">{{event.numeroDossier}}</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{event.designationDossier}}<br>{{event.nomClient}}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{event.adresse}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I can't get the data through a ng-model since each "td" is repeated.

how can i get the data specific to the line on which the user clicked ?

For example I would like to get the number displayed on the button in my controller so i can prepare my header for my next request to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the current ng-repeated item in your ng-click.

```
ng-click="submitEventChoice(event)"
```

You can then get the selected event in your controller.